# UPDATE works OK (but really, really slow) despite ORA-904 in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have an UPDATE statement with a subquery in WHERE to find the duplicates. The subquery has errors that is revealed when running the subquery itself but when running that in the UPDATE statement no error is shown and the DML runs OK (but really slow).

See the table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE RAW_table
(
  ERROR_LEVEL      NUMBER(3),
  RAW_DATA_ROW_ID  INTEGER,
  ATTRIBUTE_1      VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)
;

INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    2,  '509NTQD9Q868');
INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    2,  '509NTQD9Q868');
INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    2,  '509NTQD9Q868');
INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    3,  '509NTVS9Q863');
INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    3,  '509NTVS9Q863');
INSERT INTO RAW_table VALUES (0,    3,  '509NTVS9Q863');

COMMIT;
```

The query with error is:

```
SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1), rid
  FROM ( SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1)
              , ROWID AS rid
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
           FROM RAW_table
       )
 WHERE RN > 1;
```

It gives `ORA-00904: "ATTRIBUTE_1": invalid identifier` when run.

However, the below DML that uses the above query (as of line 4) in the WHERE statement works OK:

```
set timing on

UPDATE RAW_table
   SET ERROR_LEVEL   = 4
 WHERE (UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID) 
       IN (SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), rid
           FROM (SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID AS rid
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
                  FROM RAW_table
                )
           WHERE RN > 1
          )
;

4 rows updated.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.36
```

Why? Why? Why?

**I expected the UPDATE to fail with `ORA-00904: "ATTRIBUTE_1": invalid identifier` too.** Why it does not fail?

**The real problem, however, is** not that the UPDATE actually works, but **that it works really slow.**

When I corrected the subquery not to trigger `ORA-00904: "ATTRIBUTE_1": invalid identifier` to something like this:

```
UPDATE RAW_table
   SET ERROR_LEVEL   = 4
 WHERE (UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID) 
        IN (SELECT checked_column, rid
           FROM (SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) AS checked_column, ROWID AS rid
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
                  FROM RAW_table
                )
           WHERE RN > 1
          )
;
```

**The query accelerated nearly 400 times** on the test data set of 11.000 rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RAW_table;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     11004
1 row selected.
```

Corrected query:

```
1005 rows updated.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.28
```

Query with ORA-904:

```
1005 rows updated.
Elapsed: 00:01:48.40
```

I was not patient enough to wait till the end of 71.000 rows test:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RAW_table;
  COUNT(*)
----------
     71475
1 row selected.

Corrected query
11004 rows updated.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.60

Query with ORA-904
```

Cancelled after 30 min...

Explain plan for the query with ORA-904:

```
UPDATE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS     Cost: **2 544 985 615**  Bytes: 8 464 752  Cardinality: 4 176  
     7 UPDATE RAW_TABLE 
          6 FILTER  
               1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514  
               5 VIEW  Cost: 30 486  Bytes: 2 087 850  Cardinality: 83 514  
                    4 WINDOW SORT  Cost: 30 486  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514  
                         3 FILTER  
                              2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514
```

Explain plan for corrected query:

```
UPDATE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS     Cost: **36 637**  Bytes: 3 374 235  Cardinality: 835  
     7 UPDATE RAW_TABLE 
          6 HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI  Cost: 36 637  Bytes: 3 374 235  Cardinality: 835  
               4 VIEW VIEW SYS.VW_NSO_1 Cost: 30 486  Bytes: 168 197 196  Cardinality: 83 514  
                    3 VIEW  Cost: 30 486  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514  
                         2 WINDOW SORT  Cost: 30 486  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514  
                              1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514  
               5 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 169 282 878  Cardinality: 83 514
```

After analyzing the table the costs are plans are the same.
Explain plan for the query with ORA-904:

```
UPDATE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS     Cost: **29 381 690**  Bytes: 38  Cardinality: 2
     7 UPDATE RAW_TABLE
          6 FILTER
               1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
               5 VIEW  Cost: 427  Bytes: 1 786 875  Cardinality: 71 475
                    4 WINDOW SORT  Cost: 427  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
                         3 FILTER
                              2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
```

Explain plan for corrected query:

```
UPDATE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS     Cost: **3 123**  Bytes: 1 453 595  Cardinality: 715
     7 UPDATE RAW_TABLE
          6 HASH JOIN SEMI  Cost: 3 123  Bytes: 1 453 595  Cardinality: 715
               5 VIEW VIEW SYS.VW_NSO_1 Cost: 427  Bytes: 143 950 650  Cardinality: 71 475
                    4 VIEW  Cost: 427  Bytes: 144 879 825  Cardinality: 71 475
                         3 WINDOW SORT  Cost: 427  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
                              2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
               1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE RAW_TABLE Cost: 54  Bytes: 1 358 025  Cardinality: 71 475
```

Explain plan cost says it all, but why it is so much different?

I've just triggered a 71.000 rows test again, after computing statistics on the table, but it is already running for few minutes...

This all is on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why aliases are really, really useful.

In the query

```
UPDATE RAW_table
   SET ERROR_LEVEL   = 4
 WHERE (UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID) 
       IN (SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), rid
           FROM (SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID AS rid
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) 
                                               ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
                  FROM RAW_table
                )
           WHERE RN > 1
          )
```

`SELECT UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1)` is valid because it can be resolved as a reference to the table you are updating not to the table in the `FROM`.  With aliases, that query is equivalent to

```
UPDATE RAW_table dest
   SET dest.ERROR_LEVEL   = 4
 WHERE (UPPER (dest.ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID) 
       IN (SELECT UPPER (dest.ATTRIBUTE_1), src.rid
           FROM (SELECT UPPER (rt.ATTRIBUTE_1), rt.ROWID AS rid
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (rt.ATTRIBUTE_1) 
                                               ORDER BY rt.RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
                  FROM RAW_table rt
                ) src
           WHERE src.rid > 1
          )
```

Of course, if you had written it this way, it would be immediately clear that you were referencing the `dest.attribute_1` rather than the `src.attribute_1`.  That (and many other reasons) is why it's a good idea to alias your columns-- it makes it clear which object you intended to reference and throws an error when the intended reference is invalid rather than potentially resolving it to something you didn't intend.

Comment: Ugh.. it is, so obvious when you showed . And explains this correlated explain plan... BTW, I think you meant `WHERE src.RN> 1` not `WHERE src.rid > 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `SELECT` fails because there is no column in the subquery called `ATTRIBUTE_1`.  You would need to assign the name:

```
SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1), rid
  FROM ( SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) as ATTRIBUTE_1, 
                ROWID AS rid,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
         FROM RAW_table
       )
 WHERE RN > 1;
```

The `UPDATE` does not generate the error because it pulls the value from the outer query:

```
UPDATE RAW_table
-------^
|   SET ERROR_LEVEL   = 4
| WHERE (UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1), ROWID) IN 
|         (SELECT checked_column, rid
|          FROM (SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) AS checked_column, ROWID AS rid,
------------------------------^  This is interpreted as RAW_table.ATTRIBUTE_1
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
                 FROM RAW_table
                )
           WHERE RN > 1
          )
```

This correlation is probably not what you intend and one reason why I recommend that column names *always* be qualified (that is, include a table alias).

Comment: I think you wanted to comment over the query with the error (without `checked_column` alias) and put the ASCII art one line lower. Anyway, many thanks because I've finally got it !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1), rid
  FROM ( SELECT UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) ATTRIBUTE_1
              , ROWID AS rid
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPPER (ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) AS RN
           FROM RAW_table
       )
 WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these versions are even faster (at least they are more compact):

```
UPDATE RAW_table
SET ERROR_LEVEL = 4
WHERE ROWID <>ALL (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM RAW_table GROUP BY UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1));


UPDATE RAW_table
SET ERROR_LEVEL = 4
WHERE ROWID <>ALL (SELECT FIRST_VALUE(ROWID) OVER (PARTITION BY UPPER(ATTRIBUTE_1) ORDER BY RAW_DATA_ROW_ID) FROM RAW_table);
```

Note, `<>ALL` is equivalent to `NOT IN` - it's just my personal preference to use `<>ALL`.